# Poetry install doesn't seem to install the packages in the right place

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, uwsgi, python-poetry

So I'm having a problem for quite some time which I cannot get solved. Basically I took over a project which uses Poetry for package managing (It is a Django project). Adding packages with 'poetry add' and then installing them via 'poetry install' all works fine locally (I use a Docker container). But when pushing the changes to my server and then running 'poetry install' it says the packages are already installed. But when running the Django application, I get an internal server error saying the package doesn't exist. An example is given with the 'openpyxl' package.

pyproject.toml

```
...
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
openpyxl = "^3.0.10"
...
```

poetry.lock

```
...
[[package]]
name = "openpyxl"
version = "3.0.10"
description = "A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files"
category = "main"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.6"

[package.dependencies]
openpyxl = {version = ">=2.6.0", optional = true, markers = "extra == \"xlsx\""}

[package.extras]
all = ["markuppy", "odfpy", "openpyxl (>=2.6.0)", "pandas", "pyyaml", "tabulate", "xlrd", "xlwt"]
cli = ["tabulate"]
html = ["markuppy"]
ods = ["odfpy"]
pandas = ["pandas"]
xls = ["xlrd", "xlwt"]
xlsx = ["openpyxl (>=2.6.0)"]
yaml = ["pyyaml"]

openpyxl = [
    {file = "openpyxl-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:0ab6d25d01799f97a9464630abacbb34aafecdcaa0ef3cba6d6b3499867d0355"},
    {file = "openpyxl-3.0.10.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:e47805627aebcf860edb4edf7987b1309c1b3632f3750538ed962bbcc3bd7449"},
]
...
```

error:
[image]

Anyone experienced with Poetry who can help me with this?

Comment: what command do you use to run the django app (that leads to the `ModuleNotFoundError`)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an educated guess on few ideas you can try (without knowing more about the problem/context). For starters:

1. when running / starting your app, are you using `poetry run...` / `poetry run python...` ? I'm listing this one first, since it seems like the py environment isn't accessing the installed libs. would like to know the cmd "when running the Django application"
2. on the server, you can try to remove the lock file and re-run `poetry lock`, `poetry install` to have a 'fresh start'. The lock file you provided is the one from the server?
3. how do you use Docker, is this only on local? do you use Docker on the server as a running container? You can try dockerizing your app, and as part of the Dockerfile you copy pyproject.toml/poetry.lock files have docker RUN poetry cmds to install your deps.

again, these are shots in the dark. Some areas that can use some more understanding/detail are (a) how you start up Django app and (b) how you use Docker. If you're looking at point #3, I can elaborate on a solution for you. I've worked with quite a bit of docker+poetry apps/services.